# flutter twitter login auth

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I want to make a twitter entry through Flutter. But no code on the Internet. Do you have any suggestions about this?
These are the codes I use.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter_auth_buttons/flutter_auth_buttons.dart';
import 'package:flutter_twitter_login/flutter_twitter_login.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: MyMainPage(),
  ));
}

class MyMainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyMainPageState createState() => _MyMainPageState();
}

class _MyMainPageState extends State<MyMainPage> {
  FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  bool isLogged = false;

  FirebaseUser myUser;


  Future<FirebaseUser> _loginWithTwitter() async {
    var twitterLogin = new TwitterLogin(
      consumerKey: 'consumerKey',
      consumerSecret: 'consumerSecret',
    );

    final TwitterLoginResult result = await twitterLogin.authorize();

    switch (result.status) {
      case TwitterLoginStatus.loggedIn:
        var session = result.session;
        FirebaseUser user = await _auth.signInWithTwitter(
            authToken: session.token, authTokenSecret: session.secret);
        return user;
        break;
      case TwitterLoginStatus.cancelledByUser:
        debugPrint(result.status.toString());
        return null;
        break;
      case TwitterLoginStatus.error:
        debugPrint(result.errorMessage.toString());
        return null;
        break;
    }
    return null;
  }

  void _logOut() async {
    await _auth.signOut().then((response) {
      isLogged = false;
      setState(() {});
    });
  }



  void _logInTwitter() {
    _loginWithTwitter().then((response) {
      if (response != null) {
        myUser = response;
        isLogged = true;
        setState(() {});
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(isLogged ? "Profile Page" : "Facebook Loing Example"),
        actions: <Widget>[
          isLogged
              ? IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.power_settings_new),
                  onPressed: _logOut,
                )
              : IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.remove_red_eye),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: isLogged
            ? Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('Name: ' + myUser.displayName),
                  Image.network(myUser.photoUrl),
                ],
              )
            : Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[

                  SizedBox(height: 30.0),
                  TwitterSignInButton(
                    onPressed: _logInTwitter,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

 Future<FirebaseUser> _loginWithTwitter() async {
    var twitterLogin = new TwitterLogin(
      consumerKey: 'Y2MyConsumerKeyYKX',
      consumerSecret: 'xYXUMyConsumerSecretKeyjFAJZMyConsumerSecretKeyS3i',
    );

    final TwitterLoginResult result = await twitterLogin.authorize();

    switch (result.status) {
      case TwitterLoginStatus.loggedIn:
        var session = result.session;
        FirebaseUser user = await _auth.signInWithTwitter(
            authToken: session.token, authTokenSecret: session.secret);
        return user;
        break;
      case TwitterLoginStatus.cancelledByUser:
        debugPrint(result.status.toString());
        return null;
        break;
      case TwitterLoginStatus.error:
        debugPrint(result.errorMessage.toString());
        return null;
        break;
    }
    return null;
  }
```

The method 'signInWithTwitter' isn't defined for the class 'FirebaseAuth'.
    Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'signInWithTwitter'.

Answer (score 0):

I think your FirebaseAuth plugin is old version. There is another way also from which we can make a twitter login **_auth.signInWithCredentials()** and you simply get your credentials from **TwitterAuthProvider.getCredential()**.
Here is my method from which i complete my twitter login and get user data.

```
Future loginWithTwitter() async {
var twitterLogin = new TwitterLogin(
  consumerKey: 'your consumerKey',
  consumerSecret: 'your consumerSecret',
);

final TwitterLoginResult result = await twitterLogin.authorize();
switch (result.status) {
  case TwitterLoginStatus.loggedIn:
    var session = result.session;
    final AuthCredential credential = TwitterAuthProvider.getCredential(
        authToken: session.token, authTokenSecret: session.secret);
    AuthResult firebaseUser = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    print("twitter user name" + firebaseUser.user.displayName);
    print("twitter user email" + firebaseUser.user.email);
    print("twitter user image" + firebaseUser.user.photoUrl);
    break;
  case TwitterLoginStatus.cancelledByUser:
    break;
  case TwitterLoginStatus.error:
    break;
 }
}
```

I also recommand you to see this medium article which help you for [social media login](https://medium.com/@shubham.narkhede8/flutter-social-media-login-and-get-and-insert-data-into-mysql-database-da21c9752a7d)

Answer (score 0):

I am late. But as of today we can use [firebase_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth) with [twitter_auth_firebase](https://pub.dev/packages/twitter_auth_firebase) to login via twitter in our flutter app.

Here are the steps.

**Step 1: Add Dependencies: Add the necessary dependencies in your pubspec.yaml file.**

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core: ^1.10.0
  firebase_auth: ^4.6.0
  twitter_auth_firebase: ^0.5.0
```

**Step 2: Initialize Firebase**

Make sure you properly setup firebase project in firebase console. And be sure to initialize Firebase in your app. You can do this in the main.dart file or the entry point of your application.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

**Step 3: Configure Twitter Developer Account**

Before integrating Twitter authentication, you need to create a Twitter Developer account and set up a project on the Twitter Developer portal. Obtain the API key and API secret key from the Twitter Developer console. You need this API Key and API secret key to setup in firebase console.

1. Enable Twitter Sign In in firebase console.

Open the Firebase Console.
Select your project or create a new one.

2. Firebase Authentication:

In the left sidebar, click on "Authentication."
Navigate to the "Sign-in method" tab.

3. Twitter Configuration:

Find the Twitter section and click on "Enable."
Enter your Twitter API Key and API Secret Key in the respective fields.
Save Changes: Click on the "Save" button to save the changes.

**Step 4: Implement Twitter Authentication**
*TwitterAuthFirebase.loginViaTwitter()* : This is the static method we
are going to use for twitter login.

```
final Map<Object?, Object?>? result = await 
TwitterAuthFirebase.loginViaTwitter();

bool? success = result["success"]; // Indicates success
String? message = result["message"]; // Message for success and error
Map<Object?, Object?>? profileData = result["profile"]; // User's 
Twitter 
profile data on success
String? idToken = result["idToken"]; // User's ID token
String? accessToken = result["accessToken"]; // User's access token
Map<Object?, Object?>? error = result["error"]; // Error object, if any
```

**Full example:**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:twitter_auth_firebase/twitter_auth_firebase.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Map<Object?, Object?> result = {};


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: const Text('Twitter firebase plugin'),
    ),
    body: Column(
      children: [
        ElevatedButton(onPressed: () async {
          try {
            result = await TwitterAuthFirebase.loginViaTwitter();
          } on PlatformException {
            result = {'Failed': 'Failed to get twitter auth'};
          }

          // If the widget was removed from the tree while the 
             asynchronous platform
          // message was in flight, we want to discard the reply rather 
             than calling
          // setState to update our non-existent appearance.
          if (!mounted) return;

          setState(() {});
        }, child: const Text('Twitter Auth')),
        Center(
          child: Text('Twitter auth result: $result'),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    ),
   );
  }
  }
```